# Apply MapThread to all but one variable

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to know what is the most efficient to implement the following computation. Given three lists

```
    a = {a_1,a_2, a_3, …, a_n}
    b = {b_1,b_2, b_3, …, b_n}
    c = {c_1,c_2, c_3, …, c_n}
```

and a function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, obtain

```
     f(a_1,b_1,c_1)   f(a_1,b_1,c_2)   .....   f(a_1,b_1,c_n)  
     f(a_2,b_2,c_1)   f(a_2,b_2,c_2)   .....   f(a_2,b_2,c_n) 
     .....            .....            .....   .....
     f(a_n,b_n,c_1)   f(a_n,b_n,c_2)   .....   f(a_n,b_n,c_n)
```

I cannot find a solution not using `For`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility is to use the 3-arg version of [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread). With Sjoerd's example:

```
n = 3;
l1 = Array[a,n];
l2 = Array[b,n];
l3 = Array[c,n];
```

Using [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread):

```
Thread /@ Thread[f[l1, l2, l3], List, 2]
```

> {{f[a[1], b[1], c[1]], f[a[1], b[1], c[2]], 
>     f[a[1], b[1], c[3]]}, {f[a[2], b[2], c[1]], f[a[2], b[2], c[2]], 
>     f[a[2], b[2], c[3]]}, {f[a[3], b[3], c[1]], f[a[3], b[3], c[2]], 
>     f[a[3], b[3], c[3]]}}

Comment: Super-fast and very elegant, but does not work if `f` is already defined to generate a result. In this case you'll need something like `Thread /@ Thread[Inactive[f][l1, l2, l3], List, 2] // Activate`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way to do it with `Outer`:

```
n = 3;
l1 = Array[a, n];
l2 = Array[b, n];
l3 = Array[c, n];

Outer[
  f[#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2] &,
  Transpose @ {l1, l2},
  l3,
  1
]
```

> Out[25]= {{f[a[1], b[1], c[1]], f[a[1], b[1], c[2]], 
>         f[a[1], b[1], c[3]]}, {f[a[2], b[2], c[1]], f[a[2], b[2], c[2]], 
>         f[a[2], b[2], c[3]]}, {f[a[3], b[3], c[1]], f[a[3], b[3], c[2]], 
>         f[a[3], b[3], c[3]]}}

Comment: Or `Outer[f[Sequence @@ #1, #2] &, Transpose@{l1, l2}, l3, 1]` so you don't need to unravel `#1` manually.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};
c = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5};

Table[f[a[[j]], b[[j]], c[[k]]], {j, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way with [`Curry`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html) and [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html).

```
Through /@ Apply[Curry[f, {2, 3, 1}] /@ c] /@ Transpose@{a, b}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.